# Js extract target from loop and work it externally

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to be able to extract the values ​​from the loop and work it externally.

In practice, I would like to all "orange" (but only evaluate the last)

```
let classes = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("testY"));
classes.forEach(function (looped, i) {
        loopclass = looped;
        loopclass.style.color = "blue";
        return loopclass;
});
loopclass.style.color = "orange";
```

but only the last class turns orange...How can I recycle without staying inside?

---

**---- EDIT 1**

based on the above, I would like, in some way, to be able to recover the classes and work them out of the loop.

this is another example taken from the suggestions:

```
let classeslist = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("testY"));
let classes = classeslist.map( (el) => {
        loopedclass = el;
        return loopedclass
});
loopedclass.style.color = "orange";
```

even here, only the last class is collected and returned.

---

**---- EDIT 2.B**

ok, it starts to take shape.

The idea works but there is still the problem of chaining.

I tried to insert the constructor (elements) of FrankerZ but, of course, lock me on something.

the question now is about libs ... how do you concatenate the results of the functions ??

LIBS:

```
actions = {

    showError: (elem) => {
        elem.style.color = 'red';
    },
    highlight: (elem) => {
        elem.style.color = 'orange';
        elem.style.fontSize = '1.2em;';
    }
}

class Core {

    find(subject) //work
    {
        let name;

        if (subject.startsWith("#")) {
           ...
        }
        if (subject.startsWith(".")) {
            name = subject.split(".")[1];
            find = [...document.getElementsByClassName(name)];
        }
        if (subject.startsWith("[")) {
           ...
        }
        return find;
    }

    actionfor(target, todo) //work
    {
        target.forEach(actions[todo]);
    }

    loop(todo)
    {
        alert("direct todo");
        ???.forEach(actions[todo]);
    }
}
const core = new Core();
```

SCRIPT:

```
(function () {

       //indirect action // woooork!
       var X = core.find(".test_X");
       core.actionfor(X, "showError");

       //direct action //f**k!
       core.find(".test_Y").loop("highlight");
})();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="test_X">SIMPLE TEST CLASS</div>
<div class="test_X">SIMPLE TEST CLASS</div>
<div class="test_X">SIMPLE TEST CLASS</div>
<div class="test_Y">SIMPLE TEST CLASS</div>
<div class="test_Y">SIMPLE TEST CLASS</div>
<div class="test_Y">SIMPLE TEST CLASS</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "How can I recycle without staying inside?"

Comment: extract the classes to use them in other functions outside the loop.

I'm trying to build a method that returns the result of the loop (in this case the classes)

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return anything, and the return values of it are completely ignored. How about `.map()`?

Comment: for exemple: myLibs.find(".testY").doThisorThat();

Comment: " I'm trying to build a method that returns the result of the loop (in this case the classes)"
classes variable IS the result of running the loop. You dont copy the elements in forEach, you change them and they change in their original array as well.

Comment: eh, but I have to extract and use them from other parts, I can not stay inside that cycle. this is the goal.

"Hey, take all the classes and give it back to me that I use them here on this other side"

I'm trying to understand map but from the same result.
at this point he asks me: "How do I create a method that gives me back the classes to be able to cycle in another function?" Bah

Comment: Updated my anwer

Comment: Please, do not use hidden text, instead [edit] your question to improve its clarity.

Answer (score 3):

`classes` is an array, so if you want the last, just access it via indexes:

```js
let classes = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("testY"));

classes[classes.length - 1].style.color = 'orange';
```

```html
<span class="testY">Testing 1</span>
<span class="testY">Testing 2</span>
<span class="testY">Testing 3</span>
```

To answer your other question, as I explained above `.forEach` doesn't do what you need here. Instead use `.map()` to map your elements to an array (In this case the style of each element). Here, I'm setting them all to blue, and then returning `el.style` to be used later on. (In the next case, setting the last color to orange):

```js
let classes = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("testY"));

let styles = classes.map((el) => {
  el.style.color = 'blue';
  
  return el.style;
});

styles[styles.length - 1].color = 'orange';
```

```html
<span class="testY">Testing 1</span>
<span class="testY">Testing 2</span>
<span class="testY">Testing 3</span>
```

For an example of how you can `.doSomething()`:

```js
class LibElementHelper {
  constructor(elements) {
    this.elements = elements;
  }
  
  doSomething() {
    this.elements.forEach((el) => el.style.color = 'blue');
  }
}

class MyLib {
  getClass(className) {
    let classes = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(className));
    
    return new LibElementHelper(classes);
    
    //Or simply:
    return {
      doSomething: () => classes.forEach((el) => el.style.color = 'blue')
    };
  }
}

var lib = new MyLib();

lib.getClass("testY").doSomething();
```

```html
<span class="testY">Testing 1</span>
<span class="testY">Testing 2</span>
<span class="testY">Testing 3</span>
```

Comment: hehehe, I don't want the last one, but the opposite!

I want everyone, one by one, and use them out of the loop for other functions

Comment: yes, thank you, but this does not change me from the final goal.
I have to build a method that allows me to have the cycling classes

myLibs.GetClass ( "test"). dosomething ();

the colors were a test to understand which classes were being collected.

Comment: o... wow... ok now I study it and I tell you

(I thought my problem was stupid ... but I'm asking a difficult thing difficult hahahaha)

Answer (score 1):

Your code below:

```
let classeslist = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("testY"));
let classes = classeslist.map( (el) => {
        loopedclass = el;
        return loopedclass
});
loopedclass.style.color = "orange";
```

*even here, only the last class is collected and returned.*

No, 
All the classes are returned(elements not classes to be precise).
You don't need that map function at all since it does absolutely nothing.
It returns the same element that it received as a parameter of map funciton.
( It does nothing ).
Map function is supposed to take values from an array and change them( map them ) into something else.

One way of doing what you are trying to do...maybe.

```js
// list of shared actions that can be used everywhere
Actions = {
  showError: (elem) => {
    elem.style.color = 'red';
  },
  clearError: (elem) => {
    elem.style.color = 'black';
  },
  hide: (elem) => {
    elem.style.display = 'none';
  },
  reveal: (elem) => {
    elem.style.display = 'block';
  },
  highlight: (elem) => {
    elem.style.color = 'orange';
    elem.style.fontSize = '1.2em;';
  } ,
  underline: (elem) => {
    elem.style.textDecoration = 'underline';
  }
}
// connect actions to classes
class ClassActions {
    action(className, action) {
      [...document.getElementsByClassName(className)].forEach(Actions[action]);
      return this;
    }
}
const classActions = new ClassActions();
// Use the class actions when buttons are clicked
function commentError() {
  classActions.action('comment', 'showError');
}
function commentHide() {
  classActions.action('comment', 'hide');
}
function commentReveal() {
  classActions.action('comment', 'reveal');
}
function commentHighlight() {
  classActions.action('comment', 'highlight');
}
function postHighlightAndUnderlineAndRemoveComments() {
  classActions
  .action('post', 'highlight')
  .action('post', 'underline')
  .action('comment', 'hide');
}
```

```css
.post {
  padding: 2em;
}
.comment {
  color: gray;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class='post'>Post 1</div>
<div class='comment'>Comment 1</div>
<div class='comment'>Comment 2</div>
<div class='comment'>Comment 3</div>

<div class='post'>Post 2</div>
<div class='comment'>Comment 1</div>
<div class='comment'>Comment 2</div>
<div class='comment'>Comment 3</div>

<button onclick="commentError()">comment error</button>
<button onclick="commentHide()">comment hide</button>
<button onclick="commentReveal()">comment reveal</button>
<button onclick="commentHighlight()">comment highlight</button>
<button onclick="postHighlight()">post highlight</button>

<button onclick="postHighlightAndUnderlineAndRemoveComments()">Highlight and underline and...</button>
```

I think you shouldn't actually use any functions to change styles at all.
First - you should try to solve your problem using CSS only. Then, when you need more advanced solutions, you can try javascript.

For example, if you want to change an element with a class to "orange" then you can do it by adding another class to it.

In CSS, styles overwrite other styles. So, to have an action give a specific style to elements, try this instead.

```
// CSS
.comment {color: black;}
.comment.error { opacity: 0.8; color: red; }

// JS
[...document.getElementsByClassName("comments")].forEach((e) => {
    e.classList.add('error');
});
```

Comment: wow... ok... thanks, now I'm study it.

I have to understand what it means [... xxxxxx] in the sense that I do not know this thing written like this.

thank you very very much

Comment: It just fills array with the items from the list after "...".
For example:
a = [1,2,3];
b = [...a];
// b = [1,2,3] now

Comment: Updated the answer - You chain stuff in javascript by returning the same class that has the function you called...so that you can call another function from that class.
Btw, i also noticed you are trying to reinvent the wheel by not using the query selector.
You can get all the elements with an attribute/class/id like this.
document.querySelectorAll('[role="navigation"]');
document.querySelectorAll('.comment');
document.querySelectorAll('#elementId');
and so on. You can use all kids of complex selectors

Comment: you saw us perfect on the wheel.
It 's true, I have to understand the system but avoiding the typical jquery selector. after all to build a car ... you have to understand the wheel and know how to build it;) (learn learn I learn)

now I study what you have dedicated to me carefully. let's see if I improve.

I update you.

Comment: it is obvious that I do not want to stop at this, I have more useful things and details already made but I have to understand how to make them "jars" (I need the wheel well done hahahaha)